# Do you need to implement AIDL for a service to run outside of your apps life?

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I have a service that will send out notifications with timed tasks.  I need this service to run outside the life of the application, but I only need to access the services functions during the lifespan of the app.  Is a local service enough or do I need to implement AIDL?
Thanks.

Comment: A local service is good enough, but Commonsware will come by and tell you why it's a bad idea to keep a long running service around like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a service that will send out notifications with timed tasks.

By this, I hope you mean `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService`, such that your service is only in memory for the minimum possible time, enough to do a bit of work, raise the `Notification`, and go away. Do not write services that attempt to live forever, since that is impossible -- users or the operating system will kill off your service.

> Is a local service enough or do I need to implement AIDL?

By asking that question, I believe that you have more fundamental problems, such as not using `AlarmManager` and an `IntentService` for your periodic work. Your raise-a-`Notification`-periodically service should not be running, and hence there should be no "services functions" that you are trying to access on it.

Comment: AlarmManager is exactly what I have been looking for and the correct way to implement this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not "implement AIDL" - AIDL (android interface definition LANGUAGE) is a recommended but not mandatory convenience/abstration mechanism for generating the code needed to implement a Binder RPC interface, which is the recommended but not only way of communicating with a service.